# Getting NullPointerException tracer.currentSpan() is Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm trying to create test case for given class and want to return traceId value but getting trace.currentSpan() is null.

Here is my Class

```java
public class ConsumerService{

private final Tracer tracer;

@Autowired
private RequestService requestService;

public void consumerProductionRequest(DisclaimerRequest disclaimerRequest){
String traceId=tracer.currentSpan.context().traceId();
log.info(traceId);
if(disclaimerRequest.getReqId()==null){
disclaimerRequest.setReqId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
}
}

//Test Class
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ConsumerServiceTest{

@InjectMocks
ConsumerService consumerService;

@Autowired
Tracer tracer;

@Test
void Test(){
    Tracer tracer=Mockito.mock(Tracer.class);
    String traceId;
    Mockito.when(tracer.currentSpan().context.traceId()).thenReturn(traceId);
    DisclaimerRequest disclaimerRequest=new DisclaimerRequest();
    consumerService.consumerProductionRequest(disclaimerRequest);
}
}
```

Why am I getting tracer.currentSpan() null. I'm using JUnit 5 and new in this. Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: `currentStamp()` doesn't exist in the code you posted. Do you mean `currentSpan()`?

Comment: And minor: method names go camelCase  in java, and `Test` is a meaningless name for a test method anyway. Names should say what the things they denote are about, even in example code!

Comment: You got two answers besides that comment; mind giving feedback there?

Comment: Replace `@Autowired` with `@Mock` in your test class. DItch the `Mockito.mock` part and re-run.

Answer (score 1):

Here, in your **test** class:

```
@Autowired
Tracer tracer;
```

Turn that into

```
@Mock
Tracer tracer;
```

(and add the corresponding import to Mockito). You want that Mockito creates a mock object, and then inserts that into your object under test. Also note that your test method itself **redefines** `tracer`, thus shadowing whatever else you did on class level. Therefore that spec for `tracer` within the test method won't have any effect on the mocked Tracer instance that already got injected into your object under test.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
@BeforeAll
public static void setUp() {
    Tracing.newBuilder().build().tracer();
}
```

No need of using @Mock

Answer (score 0):

```
Tracer tracer=Mockito.mock(Tracer.class);
String traceId;
Mockito.when(tracer.currentSpan().context.traceId()).thenReturn(traceId);
```

tracer will be mock and you can see it in debug or just simply print it.
also each method returns null because you didn't specify which method will return value because spring context does not work in unit tests. In integration tests you can autowire it.

```
Mockito.when(tracer.getCurrentSpan()).thenReturn(someSpan);
Mockito.when(tracer.getCurrentSpan().getContext()).thenReturn(someContext);
String traceId;
Mockito.when(tracer.currentSpan().context.traceId()).thenReturn(traceId);
```

You have to mock getCurrentSpan and getContext methods that will solve your problem. Also you can not autowire it just use @Mock annotation. Spring context does not exist in unit tests so it won't be autowired. Spring related codes won't work. Integration test runs the spring context for you and you can autowire it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried it and getting error on getCurrentSpan() even I mocked it.